# Connection Refused - unless authenticated through Samba?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, connection, gitlab

I've had a server set up in my office for more than two years with no problems, and about a week ago it started refusing connections in an unpredictable way.

Long story short, if you try to access its Gitlab (9.5.2) website, you'll receive a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Try to push/pull/clone through http or ssh and it fails. If you try to connect to it's public Samba share through its IP address (\192.168.1.18\Public), it says the network resource is unavailable. If you try to access the Samba share through the host name (\skeleton\public) it will actually prompt for a username and password! Log in successfully and not only will the Samba share work, the IP access works, and you can access the Gitlab webpage as well as use Git through http/ssh for a little while.

I want it to allow regular access to Git from anywhere in the world using just a users regular git credentials, like it used to be before Christmas.

Any advice would be seriously helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm not 100% sure why, but Gitlab's Prometheus authentication was just outdated and was conflicting with something else. I upgraded Gitlab to 10.8 then to 11.x. everything, ssh, Samba, you name it, just works just as expected.

My advice for anyone here: it might be a total pain in the ass to upgrade something, but start there. That was my issue. You'll save yourself a lot of time and heartache before having to ask around.